# Parse plain json string value inside a response swift codable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to parse this response. Everything else is parsed - except Images. I receive it in a string but then I cannot convert it into a dictionary. This is my model.

```
struct PropertyList: Decodable {

let result: Property?
let success: Bool = false

struct Property: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let description: String?
    let propertyType: PropertyType
    let latitude, longitude: String

    let images: String?
    let areaSize:Int?
    let threeSixtyView: String?
    let threeDModel: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case propertyDescription = "description"
        case propertyType, latitude, longitude
        case threeDModel = "threeDModel"
        case images = "images"
    }
}
}


struct PropertyType: Codable {
let id: Int
let name, propertyTypeDescription: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, name
    case propertyTypeDescription = "description"
}
}
```

API Response :

```
        "name": "Al Deyar",
        "description": "Al Deyar Villa",
        "propertyType": {
            "id": 709415277471,
            "name": "villa",
            "description": "villa"
        },
        "latitude": "1",
        "longitude": "2",
        "viewOfWater": null,
        "threeDModel": "https://viewer.archilogic.com/?sceneId=80d4b3bb-98de-4279-a867-633bf67c6e72&s=m2fss0p3slst",
        "images": "[{\"id\": 1, \"image\":\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/1BEEA0B6-A2B1-4D5E-837B-9C2B00F46EE4_2048x2048.jpg\"},\n{\"id\": 2, \"image\":\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/984D2D29-2448-4B68-827F-EC912AB9AF14_2048x2048.jpg\"},\n{\"id\": 3, \"image\":\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-_0002_Layer_11_2048x2048.jpg\"},\n{\"id\": 4, \"image\":\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-_0002_Layer_10_ad2d92e2-3740-4d1d-8e9c-ed41cf89c3b2_2048x2048.jpg\"},\n{\"id\": 5, \"image\":\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-furniture_0001_Layer_21_2048x2048.jpg\"},\n{\"id\": 6, \"image\":\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-furniture_0044_Layer_5_2048x2048.jpg\"},\n{\"id\": 7, \"image\":\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-furniture_0042_Layer_3_2048x2048.jpg\"}]"

> Blockquote
```

[image: My model with values updated]

[image]

Comment: Why you don't create Image struct with id and image. And after that images will be array of the new struct?

Comment: As a proper fix, this should be fixed on the backend side.

Comment: @m1sh0 I tried it - it doesn't work Gives me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an image type as below,

```
struct PropertyImage: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var image: String?
}
```

Now, get `data` from the `images` string and `decode` an `array` of property images as below,

```
if let data = property.images.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        let images = try JSONDecoder().decode([PropertyImage].self, from: data)
        images.forEach { image in
           print(image.id)
           print(image.image)
         }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`images` is a nested JSON string which has to be decoded separately.

A solution is to declare the value containing the nested JSON string as struct (`ImageJSON`) with a `singleValueContainer` and decode the string on second level.

I left out the properties which are not in the JSON

```
let json = """
{
"success" : true,
"result" : {
    "name": "Al Deyar",
    "description": "Al Deyar Villa",
    "propertyType": {
        "id": 709415277471,
        "name": "villa",
        "description": "villa"
    },
    "latitude": "1",
    "longitude": "2",
    "viewOfWater": null,
    "threeDModel": "https://viewer.archilogic.com/?sceneId=80d4b3bb-98de-4279-a867-633bf67c6e72&s=m2fss0p3slst",
    "images":"[{\\"id\\": 1, \\"image\\":\\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/1BEEA0B6-A2B1-4D5E-837B-9C2B00F46EE4_2048x2048.jpg\\"},{\\"id\\": 2,\\"image\\":\\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/984D2D29-2448-4B68-827F-EC912AB9AF14_2048x2048.jpg\\"},{\\"id\\": 3,\\"image\\":\\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-_0002_Layer_11_2048x2048.jpg\\"},{\\"id\\": 4,\\"image\\":\\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-_0002_Layer_10_ad2d92e2-3740-4d1d-8e9c-ed41cf89c3b2_2048x2048.jpg\\"},{\\"id\\": 5,\\"image\\":\\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-furniture_0001_Layer_21_2048x2048.jpg\\"},{\\"id\\": 6,\\"image\\":\\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-furniture_0044_Layer_5_2048x2048.jpg\\"},{\\"id\\": 7,\\"image\\":\\"https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-furniture_0042_Layer_3_2048x2048.jpg\\"}]"
    }
}
"""
```

---

```
struct Response : Decodable {
    let result: Property
    let success: Bool
}

struct Property: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let propertyType: PropertyType
    let latitude, longitude: String

    let images: ImageJSON
    let threeDModel: URL
}

struct PropertyType: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, description: String
}

struct Image : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let image : URL
}

struct ImageJSON : Decodable {
    let images : [Image]

    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let imageJSONString = try container.decode(String.self)
        let imageJSONData = Data(imageJSONString.utf8)
        images = try JSONDecoder().decode([Image].self, from: imageJSONData)
    }
}
```

---

```
let data = Data(json.utf8)
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let response = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
    let images = response.result.images.images
    print(images)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Even I would say to the backend guy to fix this type of response but on the other side, I would say that it is a perfect solution. Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code :

Update your json :

```
let json = """
{
"name": "Al Deyar",
"description": "Al Deyar Villa",
"propertyType": {
    "id": 709415277471,
    "name": "villa",
    "description": "villa"
},
"latitude": "1",
"longitude": "2",
"viewOfWater": null,
"threeDModel":"https://viewer.archilogic.com/?sceneId=80d4b3bb-98de-4279-a867-633bf67c6e72&s=m2fss0p3slst",
"images": [
{"id": 1, "image": "https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/1BEEA0B6-A2B1-4D5E-837B-9C2B00F46EE4_2048x2048.jpg"},
{"id": 2, "image": "https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/984D2D29-2448-4B68-827F-EC912AB9AF14_2048x2048.jpg"},
{"id": 3, "image": "https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-_0002_Layer_11_2048x2048.jpg"},
{"id": 4, "image": "https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-_0002_Layer_10_ad2d92e2-3740-4d1d-8e9c-ed41cf89c3b2_2048x2048.jpg"},
{"id": 5, "image": "https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-furniture_0001_Layer_21_2048x2048.jpg"},
{"id": 6, "image": "https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-furniture_0044_Layer_5_2048x2048.jpg"},
{"id": 7, "image": "https://neigborhood-images.s3.amazonaws.com/property/EBARZA-furniture_0042_Layer_3_2048x2048.jpg"}
]
}
"""
```

Update your codable class :

```
struct Property : Codable {

    let descriptionField : String?
    let images : [Images]?
    let latitude : String?
    let longitude : String?
    let name : String?
    let propertyType : PropertyType?
    let threeDModel : String?
    let viewOfWater : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case descriptionField = "description"
        case images = "images"
        case latitude = "latitude"
        case longitude = "longitude"
        case name = "name"
        case propertyType = "propertyType"
        case threeDModel = "threeDModel"
        case viewOfWater = "viewOfWater"
    }
}


struct PropertyType : Codable {

    let descriptionField : String?
    let id : Int?
    let name : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case descriptionField = "description"
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
    }
}


struct Images : Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let image : String?
}




if let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    do {
        let jsonModel = try decoder.decode(Property.self, from: jsonData)
        print(jsonModel)
    } catch {
        print("Error = \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - thats the issue. I cant ask the backend developer to change it